# special character encoding C# and Ironpython

Tags: c#, special-characters, ironpython

I am facing an encoding issue while trying to pass a string from two C# modules using Ironpython code as a bridge.

Special characters like € , © gets distorted when the string is received by the recipient module.

Can anyone please advise if its a IronPython issue ? and how to fix this type of issue

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [Frequently Asked Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).  
If you want help with your code, please post it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are doing something wrong. There is no issues with encoding and IronPython. Check encoding for script you load before..